# How to pass JDBC results to another thread

Tags: jmeter

Let me explain my test plan...

I have a **setUp Thread Group** which executes a **JDBC select query** and stores the records in different variables like below.

[image]

Then i pass the total number of records count to next **Thread Group** to fix the number of iterations by using **BeanShell Assertion**.

```
${__setProperty(totalRecords,${UCID_#})}
```

Now i want to pass the variables to next thread group and use the values one by one in each iteration like below.

```
${__V(UCID${__counter(TRUE,)})}
```

Setproperty is not working in this case. Is there any other ways available?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing only `UCID_#` value to the next Thread Group. It cane be accessed using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like

```
${__P(totalRecords,)}
```

---

As [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) all below examples are in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/)

If you want to pass **all** variables which start with `UCID` to another Thread Group you need to take a slightly different approach:

1. In setUp Thread Group convert JMeter Variables into JMeter Properties. Example code you can use in the [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion):

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('UCID_#') as int, {
       props.put('UCID_' + it, vars.get("UCID_$it"))
   })
   props.put('UCID_#', vars.get('UCID_#'))
   ```
2. In "normal" Thread Group convert them back using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

   ```
   1.upto(props.get('UCID_#') as int, {
       vars.put('UCID_' + it, props.get('UCID_' + it))
   })
   vars.put('UCID_#', props.get('UCID_#'))
   ```

Once you do this you __V() function should start working as expected.

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)